# Background-image CSS does not load

Tags: html, css, css-backgrounds

In an HTML webpage I created, a stylesheet is attached that, among other things, uses "background-image" to add an image from a CDN, using this code _

```
BODY{
background-image: url(https://CDN/FILE.jpg);
}
```

This seems to just create a blank background -- however, when I turn off the style on the Element Inspector and then turn it on again, it works perfectly fine. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot `""` around the link.
Try `background-image: url("https://CDN/FILE.jpg");`

I'd suggest making an example in codepen if this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

Your image address doesn't work

```css
body {
  background:center / cover no-repeat url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1662436267867-474127614b7a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxlZGl0b3JpYWwtZmVlZHwyfHx8ZW58MHx8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60");
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

<p>This page has an image as the background!</p>
```

Comment: I checked it, and the image address does work.